# At what point in the .NET Pipeline do Bundles get written in to the HTML? - MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I've got an application that Bundling works fine on, however I have to go and demonstrate the application away from our network, so I'm transferring it to a VM on my laptop.

On my laptop The bundles aren't rendering on the page, and when I mean not rendering, I mean there's literally nothing there. No Script or CSS files either in a bundle, or individually.

I'm just trying to debug the problem. The bundles all appear to be in the `BundleTable`, but not sure where I should be looking next.

If anyone could point me in the direction of a resource that gives me more information about exactly when and where bundles are written to the response I'd be most appreciative.

The laptop is running Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4, and the problem occurs on both IISExpress and the visual Studio Development server.

**EDIT:** Feel like a bit of an idiot. The problem is due to the virtual directories on my dev machine and on my laptop being configured differently. And so, whilst the Bundles were being correctly, the scripts and CSS files were not being added to the bundles, so hence nothing to render.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue, maybe for the same reason: on my development machine I had a lot of scripts that went into the project with time. When running the web application locally, the scripts were found, but not so on the production server. I realized that I had not added the additional scripts to the project's *Scripts* folder, therefore they had not been included when deploying on the production server (via the **Publish** method within VS). Same applies for missing images on the production server, btw.

Comment: A good tip, but's not happening in my case. I simply copied the entire solution directory on to my laptop, and all files are in the right place.